# Reinstalling critical files in Recovery Mode

Tags: kubuntu, dpkg, live-usb, recovery-mode

I might have accidentaly purged some critical files, causing my Kubuntu 14.04 to not boot past the startup logo.

By entering the recovery mode from a LiveUSB, and running `sudo apt-get install -f`, I am told that there are some unmet dependencies. So I am guessing those are the files that I purged.

Is there a way of installing all crucial files in recovery mode to get Kubuntu to run smoothly again?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Boot from liveUSB.

Open a terminal.

Determine your HDD system partition.

```
exec sudo -i
fdisk -l
```

Mount your HDD system partition. X is the drive letter. Y is the partition number. Substitute the correct partition like sda1, sdb5, etc. continue running:

```
mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

Example: `mount /dev/sda5 /mnt`

If you have a separate boot partition, mount your boot partition:

```
mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/boot
```

Example: `mount /dev/sdb6 /mnt/boot`

Mount the critical virtual filesystems:

```
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
```

Chroot into your HDD system device:

```
chroot /mnt
```

Now reinstall kubuntu:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop
apt-get install -f
apt-get dist-upgrade
exit
```

And reboot

Comment: thanks for your fast response. tried your method but could only get to the `for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do mount -B $i /mnt$i; done` part. It gives me this error:
    `mount: mount point /mnt/dev does not exist`

   `mount: mount point /mnt/dev/pts does not exist`

    `mount: mount point /mnt/proc does not exist`
    `mount: mount point /mnt/sys does not exist`
    `mount: mount point /mnt/run does not exist`
This is usually where all other methods I have tried failed, too. I dont know how to fix this.

Comment: From running `fdisk -l`, I get this warning about the SSD that my system is on: `WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.`

Comment: ok I have tried your method again, with also enabling chroot to have internet access (without this, any updates could not be fetched): `cp -L /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf`. Now when I try and run `apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop`, I get a list of packages with unmet dependencies (about 100 of them)?? And the message `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: You can get a list of actual held packages with: dpkg --get-selections | grep hold. And use  apt-get to try to install  held packages one on one apt-get install <packagename>